# E2E Testing: Testing field limits?

Tags: test-design

So I'm curious about this, and being in my first automation job I wasn't sure how others typically handled this.

Let's say we have a new "section" of a form with 3 fields. The 3 fields are mandatory and have various alphanumeric length requirements. (1-5 characters alphanumeric or 1-9 characters numeric/etc...)

Obviously, we want to verify that the fields are required before being able to continue on. But I'm curious at how deep someone would go with the verification:

- Should we verify EACH field individually is "required" before continuing (3 different tests)
- Do we both with the min-max and field character types? This feels like edge case testing and for a UI test seems extensive.

I feel like both of the above could qualify for unit/integration tests and in an E2E scenario would maybe be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, E2E testing should focus on testing the end-to-end flow of the application from the user's perspective, rather than testing individual field validations. For example, you would want to test that the user is unable to submit the form without filling in the mandatory fields, rather than testing each field individually.

However, it is also important to consider the requirements of the application and the potential impact of a failure in the field validation. If it is important that the fields are validated correctly, then it may make sense to include tests that specifically check each field's validation rules.

As for the min-max and character types, it's a good idea to test the edge cases, as it helps in ensuring that the application behaves as expected and handles the unexpected inputs.

In summary, it is a balance between testing the end-to-end flow and ensuring that the specific validation rules are working as expected. You can prioritize the tests based on the requirements and the impact of a failure in that particular validation.